# How do I rename multiple files?

Tags: 16.04, files, rename

I have several files in the same folder that have one element in common in the names.  How do I rename the files so that the common element in the names is deleted?

[image: Example]

Comment: Use one of the text listing commands and copy/paste the text to your question.  This will make it easier for us to text the text against the commands provided. you can get a text listing with commands such as `ls` or better `ls -1`.

Comment: If you google "ubuntu bulk rename", you'll find many other related questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rename`

```
rename -n 's/\(U\)//' *.bin
```

This will delete the "(U)" part of the file name from all `.bin` files.

If you are happy with changes that `rename` will make then take out the "-n" option which is No Action, that only shows what files would have been renamed.

Answer (score 0):

The way I always do it: Thunar bulk rename.

#### Install Thunar:

```
sudo apt install thunar
```

Now open bulk rename (if you're using basic 16.04 version, just go to dash home and type bulk: you'll get it.)

Options are pretty obvious from there.

I know, I know, some geek will tell me I should have done it from the command line.  And that's doable too, but you'd need to be a bit more specific on exactly what you want to get a specific command.